# Multiple JavaPairDStream from single JavaStreamingContext(JavaReceiverInputDStream)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a queue from which I'm reading data using Spark Streaming. I need to write this data (after some calculations) into 2 different tables(calculations are different for both tables). I observed that my code executes only the first JavaPairDStream and not the other. I have output action on both PairStreams.

I also noticed that if the data in the queue is small - lets say just 1 message then it is inserted into both tables but is not the case when the data in the queue is large

My code looks as follows -

```
public static void main(String ar[]) {
   JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createJavaStream(streamCtx, String.class, rabbitMqConParams, messageHandler);

//this is first pair stream
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> map1 = receiverStream.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, Integer>() {...}
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> red1  = map1.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {...}
red1.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>>() {
 //i write to hbase from here to "x" table
}

//this is second pair stream
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> map2 = receiverStream.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, Integer>() {...}
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> red2  = map2.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {...}
red2.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>>() {
 //i write to hbase from here to "y" table
}
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Please also note that there are some 30K messages in the queue already when I was starting to run this in the cluster. And this queue is a RabbitMQ. Please also note that when I say fewer messages, I meant once the Streaming was running in cluster, I kept pushing messages into the queue and it worked fine. Does this have any impact?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the above code. I am also doing the same thing for one of my use-case.

It might be possible that, the code that is writing the data in **`HBase`** is taking time.

Can you please try setting the below property in **`SparkConf`** to control the streaming input rate. It will help you in debugging the issue.

```
// In case if reading from Kafka
conf.set("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", 100);

// In case of other streams
conf.set("spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate", 100);
```

The above property controls the maximum input rate of the receiver (number of records per second) at which each receiver will receive data. Effectively, each stream will consume at most **`100`** records per second. Refere http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-streaming for more details about streaming configuration.